# Getting null when converting Postgres database to JSON

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I'm trying to convert a table in my Postgres database with PHP. The thing is, I'm getting null when I run the script, and no data is fetched.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$connection = pg_connect("host=xxx port=5432 dbname=xxxxx user=xxxxx password=xxxxxxxxx");

$result = pg_query('SELECT * FROM deals'); 


$rows = array();
while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode(array_values(pg_fetch_all($result)));
?>
```

This is the actual link for the code:

http://send.easyrent-brasil.com/api.php

Comment: You're building up a result array in `$rows`, but then appear to be ignoring it and calling `pg_fetch_all`. You should probably do one or the other.

Comment: i changed some code

http://send.easyrent-brasil.com/api.php

but now its not printing anything

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried eliminating `null` values like

```
$result = pg_query('SELECT * FROM deals WHERE *filed* != 'null');
```

or

```
$result = pg_query('SELECT * FROM deals WHERE *filed* != '');
```